# Why same process takes longer in Rust than in Python?

Tags: python, rust

I have a very simple code in `python`

```py
x = "ABCD ss xx ta"
l = x.split(" ")

for i, y in enumerate(l):
    print(f"{i}: {y}")
```

which takes

```sh
real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.026s
sys     0m0.004s
```

I have done the same thing in `Rust` which is compiled - it should be faster

```rust
fn main() {
    let split = "ABCD ss xx ta".split(" ");
    for (i, s) in split.enumerate() {
        println!("{}:{}", i, s)
    }
}
```

which takes

```sh
real    0m0.159s
user    0m0.142s
sys     0m0.012s
```

I would like to ask here, why is compiled `Python` faster here than compiled `Rust` which I'm running with `cargo` `run` (already compiled)?

Comment: If the code performs I/O, that's usually the bottlneck, so compiling versus interpreting makes little difference. The difference is in the I/O libraries.

Comment: This is not really a valid test. The first run will generally be much slower. Run each one ~100 times and see what happens overall. Also, keep in mind that many factors are at play here. For example, part of Rust's overhead may be loading DLLs or similar.

Comment: @Barmar. Where do you see I/O? (Besides the print statement)

Comment: It's hard to guess for such a short program where it's spending its time. It will be affected eg by whether a needed shared library is cached in RAM. You can try running with `strace` or similar to see the timing of various calls.

Comment: If you're only using `cargo run`, then it's running in an unoptimized debug mode. Use the `--release` flag to enable optimizations for the rust code.

Comment: I suspect using `cargo run` is also taking a big chunk of time. Try running the compiled executable directly.

Comment: with --release its faster about 0.002 sec

Comment: calling `rustc` it takes  real 0m0.561s, user 0m0.501s, sys 0m0.140s which is even longer

Comment: Using rust means that you are including compile  time. Benchmark the compiled binary directly.

Comment: I got this values on binary file
real 0m0.001s
user 0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s

this is satisfying enough, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, i'm no python expert, but python as well as python3 does not run your code, i get errors. Changing it to:

```
x = "ABCD ss xx ta"
l = x.split(" ")

for i, y in enumerate(l):
    print(i , y)
```

Gives me (python 3):

```
real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Now for the real reason, I believe you are compiling with debug symbols as well as including the compliation time in your assertion. When I build your crate with `cargo build --release` and run the binary directly (which is put in ./target/release/), i get:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Which is far superior, (as rust normally is:))!

Comment: Your Python is probably older than 3.6, which is the first version to support f-strings.